# Parent NestedScrollView disabling all functions

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview

So, I have my activity layout like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_root_coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_activity_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_activity_collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/actionBarSize">

            <include layout="@layout/include_toolbar" />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/below_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main_activity_sub_category_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/layout_margin_list"
                android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_bigger" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_activity_fragment_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />


            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/main_activity_progress_bar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


    <vb.uzoni.ui.view.BottomMenuView
        android:id="@+id/main_activity_bottom_menu_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now, I need to implement chat funcionality in one of the fragments. The `ChatFragment` layout looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/actionBarSize"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/single_message_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In preview window, it looks like this:[image]

But in reality, it uses the `NestedScrollView` as parent and it pushes my `EditText` and `Button` to the bottom of the `NestedScrollView`.

What I want to do here is next:
1. Disable all scrolling from `NestedScrollView`
2. I don't want to inherit the scrollable feature of the `NestedScrollView` so I can position my `Button` and `EditText` to the bottom of the view where they will always be visible.

How is that possible?

**EDIT**

Now problem with `NestedScrollView` in fragment:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/sub_categories_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/homeDividerColor" />


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

It doesn't show the recycler view, and doesnt do the appscrolling behaviour...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `NestedScrollView`. Instead you can use -

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <!-- Replace your fragment in this container -->
           <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_activity_fragment_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/main_activity_progress_bar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Looks like, I eliminated your `NestedScrollView` problem

Comment: I need NestedScroll view since in some fragments I have funcionalities that go with AppBar scroll behaviour...

Comment: Try to put Scrollable content like `NestedScrollView` or `recyclerview` in our fragment instead. And put `app:layout_behavior` in that scroll able view too.

Comment: It won't work, since I have FrameLayout and BottomMenuView below app bar..

Comment: Ta da.. I told you that ;-)

Comment: Yeah,now another problem...:) when I put 'NestedScrollView' inside my fragment layout, it doesn't show the recycler view. Please see edited question

Answer (score 0):

you can try putting your `NestedScrollView` inside your `Framelayout` container. and dynamically replace the container.

It will remove the `Nestedscrollview` scrolling problem

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_root_coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_activity_fragment_container"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

             <--Your contents-->
            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```